# TDI class error

Tags: visual-foxpro

For compatibility reasons I have to work on visual FoxPro. So I decided to freshen up the look of the old app using TDI class.

When I run the main prg from FoxPro IDE example works perfectly, when I build exe and check the option "Run after build" everything still works. But when I just launch exe the form starts opening, shows a window for a second and then closes.

How can I try to find the problem? Tried adding messageboxes, but after certain place in code I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your code doesn't have READ EVENTS.

Answer (score 3):

As Tamar pointed out, you forgot to add a READ EVENTS.

Without a READ EVENTS, VFP runs your code, reaches to the end and there is nothing there saying it to "wait and do event processing loop" so it finishes. A "READ EVENTS" provides the needed wait state (in case of IDE you already have it). 
ALSO, remember to add a CLEAR EVENTS where you want to really end and exit your application (typical location menu "Exit"). Without it you would need to use task manager to kill the app.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I made a mistake in if condition so read events were not executed.